# Libraries to play .mod audio files in C++ or Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, audio

Libraries to play .mod audio files in C++ or Delphi
Any body know of any?

Comment: this is a really old format yes?  I remember a .mod file that was popular on the Amiga is that the one?

Answer (score 2):

[FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/index.php/fmod) is a audio library that will play MOD files.  I've used it in a C++ program before, and it looks like it has an API for Delphi, too.